# How to pass a component to a component in Polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

Suppose a component  is composed of 3 internal components, where `<outer-tag>`'s shadow DOM looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>The Outer Tag</h1>
    <my-tag1/>
    <my-tag2/>
    <my-tag3/>
</div>
```

Now let's say that `<outer-tag>`, `<my-tag1/>` and `<my-tag3/>` were always the same. But I want `<my-tag2>` to be pluggable. i.e. passed in. How would I do that in Polymer?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question right, you are looking for a way to distribute random children into the outer-tag's DOM ([Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-distribution)).

Here's how you would do it in your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Outer-inner tags</title>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="outer-tag">
    <template>
        <div>
            <h1>The Outer Tag</h1>
            <my-tag1></my-tag1>

            <!-- Tell the <outer-tag> that something will go in here -->
            <content select=".tag2"></content>

            <my-tag3></my-tag3>
        </div>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'outer-tag'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
<dom-module id="random-tag">
    <template>
        <div>
            <h2>Random Tag</h2>
            <div>I'm a random component</div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'random-tag'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- Here's how to put them together -->
<outer-tag>
    <random-tag class="tag2"></random-tag>
</outer-tag>


</body>
</html>
```

Instead of ".tag2" you could more generally write "random-tag". The `select` attribute accepts CSS-like selectors.