# how do I create polymer components that contain other polymer components

Tags: polymer

How do I create polymer components that contain other polymer elements ?

Can someone either point me at an example or give a working exampe please ?

Comment: Do you mean using other components in template or as children of your component element?

Comment: Can you be more specific. Do you want to extend other component or just use them like any other html tag like div?

Comment: To create my own polymer component that contains child polymer elements. In this case a new feed element that contains an iron-list and iron-ajax components/elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a component to a component in Polymer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774028/how-to-pass-a-component-to-a-component-in-polymer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for the tag **`<content>`**

have a look here

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom

ex.

```
<dom-module id="simple-content">
  <template>
    <content id="myContent"></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'simple-content',
      ready: function() {
        var distributed = this.getContentChildren('#myContent');
        console.log(distributed.length);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<simple-content> <div>THIS IS MY CHILD CONTENT</div> </simple-content>
```